# Json string to json object conversion

Tags: java, javascript, android, json

I have looking to similar questions but i was not able to solve my problem .I have tried parsing my json response both into a Json array and Json object but every time , i am getting this exception of string to json object. 
I guess may be the problem is with my Json response.

```html
results = { "type": 1, "user_log": "ahsan.tahir.92_/var/www/html/2014-10-11__15-54-52__50sec.txt_res", "freq": 0.01, "coordina": [ [-37], [-9], [-20], [-12], [-22], [-9], [-22], [-15], [-25], [-7], [-20], [-12], [-20], [-9], [-25], [8], [-23], [-11], [-18], [-13], [-19], [-10], [-21], [-12], [-25], [-11], [-17], [-12], [-22], [-13], [-21], [3] ], "tot_time": 40.11, "tot_distace": 100, "stroke_each_pool": [ [16], [16] ], "tot_stroke": [ [16], [16] ], "split": [ [20.22], [19.89] ], "timing_turn": 7.04, "cycle_Rate_l": [ [2.22], [2.2680001] ], "cycle_Rate_r": [ [2.224], [2.27] ], "mean_velocity": [ [2.4727993], [2.5138261] ], "stroke_length": [ [3.125], [3.125] ], "stroke_freq": [ [79.077431], [77.419357] ], "roll_peaks": [ [-44.10043335], [55.79428101], [-61.51541138], [54.7466507], [-62.09820557], [55.01488495], [-62.48770142], [53.44023132], [-70.32449341], [51.8399353], [-65.84837341], [53.5617981], [-63.50210571], [55.9821167], [-62.37905121], [39.42669678], [-43.44207764], [63.20912933], [-59.19660187], [50.6708374], [-63.8214798], [54.57595062], [-63.31864166], [53.82037354], [-66.93650818], [52.36277008], [-65.23461151], [52.89829254], [-62.78508759], [51.17367554], [-62.87123108], [59.13114929] ], "mean_roll_dx": [ [52.475822], [54.73027] ], "mean_roll_sx": [ [61.531971], [60.950779] ], "std_roll_dx": [ [5.4471908], [4.3127728] ], "std_roll_sx": [ [7.6123171], [7.4134283] ], "mean_roll": [ [57.003899], [57.840527] ], "std_roll": [ [7.9220791], [6.6817732] ], "mean_pitch": [ [-5.5227709], [-5.2282872] ], "std_pitch": [ [-5.5227709], [-5.2282872] ], "clean_stroke_time": [ [15.92], [16.84] ], "errore": 227, "fatal_error": { "_ArrayType_": "double", "_ArraySize_": [0,0], "_ArrayData_": null } }
```

and i am parsing it like this :

```html
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(in);
            JSONObject sys  = reader.getJSONObject("results");
```

Any idea what am i missing here ?

My exception is as follows :

```html
org.json.JSONException: Value type of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Is "results =" part of your response?

Comment: remove "result=" from your json response , thn only it will be valid json string

Comment: validate your JSON first :http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
results = {rest of response here}
```

is not valid JSON.

Perhaps you meant to return this:

```
{"results": {rest of response here}}
```

... or just

```
{rest of response here}
```

Comment: Yes , this was the problem . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no `results` field in the `results` string you have posted, is that the issue. In any case, please go ahead and reformat your question to more accurately reflect what you are doing, and include the error message you are seeing.

Actually, are you referring to the error message in the JSON output? That seems to be a JSON-encoded error message that was output by whatever service you called. There seems to be some issue with the data you are passing to that service.

Answer (score 0):

I may have Misunderstood your question, but where are you parsing the Json response using something like
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(strippedJSON); 
where strippedJSON  the response received from API.

Comment: I was of the view , that just passing the string response to the constructor of json object Like:
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(ResponseString);
will do the job ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `reader` object is your `results` object itself.

```
JSONObject resultsJSON = new JSONObject(in);
System.out.println("User Log: " + resultsJSON.get("user_log"));
```

You're getting the exception because there's no `results` object in your input JSON string i.e. you're receiving your `results` object without a JSON wrapper around it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using javascript
try this

var parsed_data = JSON && JSON.parse(results) || $.parseJSON(results);